# Getting width of a large bitmap gives NullPointerException in Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-asynctask, compression

I'm downloading an image from a url which has large pixel size. Fetching of this bitmap is done in AsyncTask. The code is as follows:

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {

        public Bitmap image;

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                URLConnection conn = new URL(params[0]).openConnection();
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) conn.getContent());
                if (image == null)
                    throw new RuntimeException("Could not read image");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return image;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            mBitmap = bitmap;
        }
    }.execute(imageUrl);
```

Now, When i'm trying to get the width of the bitmap as follow:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

It gives me NullPointerException on mBitmap.getWidth(). I checked with other images with lower screen resolution, that worked though. I tried to compress the bitmap too but it failed.
Any suggestions?? Thanks in advance.

> Update: Logcat is as follows:
>
> **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference**
>
> **The Second snippet is used in another asynctask which is called after the bitmap calling asynctask.**

Comment: is it getWidth or that mBitmap is null ?

Comment: @ApriOri updated the question.

Comment: Show us the full code please.

Comment: Are you sure that another exception does not occur? Since the `return image;` is outside the try...catch block it is possible that, for example, a ClassCastException occurs when trying to cast `conn.getContent()`. Have you checked that it actually returns an instance of `InputStream`? Or maybe an exception thrown by the URL constructor?

Comment: Yes, i did check and there is only nullpointer exception i got that is mentioned above.

Comment: Do you check whether the AsyncTask is finished yet with `getStatus()` method? This will check if  `onPostExecute(Result)` has finished?

Comment: @skeidsberget2365 I have written the 1st snippet in a dunction. I tried to check value of mBitmap in onPostExecute. It gave me not null there, but when i checked it at the next line the function is called, it gave me mBitmap null there.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the `AsyncTask` is that `onPostExecute` it will set the value of `mBitmap`:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        mBitmap = bitmap; // sets this value asynchronously
    }
```

You simply fetch its value before it is set, that's why it is `null`.

> The Second snippet is used in another asynctask which is called after the bitmap calling asynctask.

If you `execute` another `AsyncTask` it does not mean that your previous one has already finished execution.

Comment: The second code is written in another asynctask and it called after the bitmap caling asynctask. so second asynctask will be queued  and I have mentioned in my question that it works for small resolution images.

Comment: Just because it is executed after the first it does not mean that the first task is completed at that time. When you call `execute` it is not processed yet.

Comment: from AsyncTask docs - "onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes." Doesn't that mean that `doInBackground(Params)` is finished?

Comment: That's true. But your other code which tries to use the value in `mBitmap` is not called from `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Excatly. I did check in the log of result got from onPostExecute but when i'm assigning it to the global variale, it gives null.

Comment: where is mBitmap declared and with what scope?

Comment: @skeidsberget2365 it is declared as class variable and declared as: private Bitmap mBitmap;

Comment: I have a question. After you download your bitmap, You will set image view? what do you do?

Comment: @redAllocator i'm convert that bitmap into blur image throgh renderscript and then i'm setting the image to an imageview.